# How many of us play for points on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, fun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we really want to help or its just because of the reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32249/do-we-really-want-to-help-or-its-just-because-of-the-reputation-points)

How many of us play for points on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Don't really understand the question...

Comment: Not you, evidently. Judging by your recent questions.

Comment: How many of us post a random question every 2 minutes?

Comment: Play for the protine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870987/how-much-protine-do-we-get-from-on-banana-and-egg-and-apple

Answer (score 4):

**42 of us**, no more, no less

Answer (score 0):

He who dies with the most points.... is Jon Skeet.

Comment: Jon Skeet never dies, his life counter just overflows.